# Getting error in jenkins while .net project publish "No home directory is available for .NET SDK '.NET4.5'"

Tags: jenkins, .net-4.5, .net-sdk

I am trying to publish website using .Net 4.5 but getting error mentioned in the subject.

The option selected for Build steps is as follow,

".NET: Publish project (publish)"

Since I am new to jenkins I am not aware of the error I am getting.

After few online examples I found that the SDK installation path has to be mentioned abd I suggested by many people the path should be like "C:\Program Files\dotnet" but I could not find such path on my server. Does that mean the SDK 4.5 is not installed on my server? please help me to understand and resolve this issue.
refer screenshot for reference,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: #1 Is your jenkins in the same server of IIS ? #2 netframework or netcore? #3 Jenkins needs a well configured shell. Try the commands `dotnet publish...` without jenkins, I mean with pure cmd o power and share us the result

Comment: #Jenkins is on separate server  #. Net framework

Comment: JRichardsz - Dotnet command on command promt gives erroras "dotnet is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: That is the error. Re install dotnet and try with pure cmd  before jenkins attempts.